# Statistical Significance for a single patient

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I have the mean values for a blood test from only 1 patient before and after treatment. My supervisor asked me to find statistical significance.
I have the mean value of 4 parameters. Would it make sense to find statistical significance of a single patient? If so, what kind of test should I perform?

Comment: If you have several measurements of the same type before treatment and several after, then a two-sample t test could be used (if measurements are nearly normally distributed) or possibly a two-sample Wilcoxon test (if not normal). If by 'parameters' you mean different kinds of measurements (hematocrit, fasting glucose, liver enzymes, etc.) then I'm not sure what the meaning of an average would be. // Cam you be more specific about the numbers and types of blood test results you have.

Comment: By parameters I meant hematocrits, glucose etc. And I have basically the mean value of these parameters before and after. But is only a single number. I mean mean value of glucose before and mean value of glucose after

Comment: OK.. This is a difference in terminology between fields. In statistics, parameters are numerical quantities that specify which member of a parametric family of distributions is intended. For example, in the family $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma),$ the parameters are $\mu$ and $\sigma.$ if $\mu=0, \sigma=1,$ then we have the standard normal dist'n. // In CS, one use of the word 'parameter' is an expression that helps to specify a particular kind of computation. E.g., in R stat. software the parameter, `var.eq=T` in the function `t.test` specifies a pooled t test (not a Welch t test) is intended.

Comment: You might have enough background data to do discriminant analysis categories for specific patients at specifiic stages--such as 'candidate for surgey', 'successful post op', 'unsuccessful post op'. Then given a profile of several blood tests for a new individual you might be able to classify them as to category.  Perhaps google 'discriminant analysis', especially for examples of Fisher's now-famous Iris data. Iris flowers are categorized as belonging to specific species according to lengths and widths off petals and sepals (4 measurements).

Answer (score 1):

Since you have only $1$ measurement it is meaningless to ask about statistical significance. However, if you have a model of the population distribution of those parameters (for instance, suppose one knows that members of the general population have their glucose level approximately normally distributed with some known mean and standard deviation) then you can compare the absolute value of the before/after difference to the population standard deviation as a proxy for statistical significance. A better way to phrase your question involves formulating a null hypothesis (that there is no change from before/after). Only if the difference is significantly larger than the population standard deviation could one gain evidence to reject this null hypothesis.